# What are the "default values" that .Net sets all of the values in a class to if the class does not have a constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, class, default-constructor

In c# using .Net, if you create a class with an uninitialized field and without a constructor, then create an instance of the class with the new keyword, .Net sets the value of the field to the "default value". What exactly does that mean? Is there ever a situation where the value would be set to Null?

Comment: "Is there ever a situation where the value would be set to Null?" Yes. Reference types will default to null.

Comment: Take a look https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/default-values-table

Comment: Basically the default is 0, which means different things based on the type.  For references that a null, for value types it's whatever value maps to the equivalent of all the bits set to 0.  So for number types it's 0 or boolean it's false.

Comment: `default(whateverType)`, to be specific. As juharr says, that'll be `null` for any reference type, and the appropriate value of `0` for any numeric type, `false` for `bool`, etc.

Comment: .Net fills by `0` the memory allocated for the class instance. So it will be `null`, `0`, `0.0`, `false` etc.

Answer (score 6):

Like Johnny mentioned in the comments, [this table lists the default values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/default-values-table) for .NET types. The default value of a reference-type field is `null`.

Comment: Thanks for the table, very interesting!  (In the old days, I'd make it a 'favorite', but that's getting more obsolete, now)....

Answer (score 5):

The default value is defined on a per-type basis. In general, any reference type will default to `null`.

You can find a full list of default values based on the type in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/default-values-table).

Furthermore, you can find out empirically by explicitly using the [`default` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default) and checking (e.g. in the debugger) what value was returned:

```
var x = default(string);
var y = default(int);
```